# reducing symmetries from $D_n$ to $C_n$ by adding a tick

Tags: group-theory

The dihedral group $D_n$ is the set of symmetries of a regular polygon with $n$-sides.
In [this](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf) summary by Milne, it's written that:

> By adding a tick at each vertex of a regular polygon, we can reduce its symmetry group
> from $D_n$ to $C_n$.

I'm trying to visualize - how does 'adding a tick' look? why does it reduce the number of symmetries to $C_n$?

The way I see it, it's adding the symbol ' to the vertex name, which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

While writing the question I've thought of an answer. It's about making an asymmetric change near each vertex. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: A tick could also mean $\checkmark$, again something that rules out reflection as a symmetry but if you go round adding them in the right way you preserve rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates what is meant.
[image: Here are the pictures]

Comment: The OP said he was trying to vizualize what was meant. The first picture exactly illustrates what was meant. In particular, it shows what "adding a tick" means.